# Magento2 facebook share response in product view page

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

I have added facebook share link in product view page, it is sharing the product, but i would like get the shared response from facebook in my file in magento2.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script async defer src="connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script> 
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
    <a target="_blank" href="facebook.com/sharer/…" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: i have added  facebook share link in view page by using custom module

Comment: i want the response after the product share

Comment: yes, but what have you tired to achieve this? this is not a coding service

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2">
    </script>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
    </div>

Comment: i have added the above code to share my product

Comment: ok. 1. please add code to your question so it doesn't get burried in the comments 2. what have you tired to get the shared response from facebook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89924/discussion-between-shivashankar-m-and-philipp-sander).